# 正規表現で一致しない単語にマッチさせるには

Tags: 正規表現, fluentd

お世話になります。

正規表現にて一致しない単語にマッチさせる方法について調べているのですが、ご教授お願いします。一致させたいパターンは以下です。

検索文字

```
"hoge1": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","hoge2": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy","hoge3": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

一致させたい単語

```
"hoge1": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx""hoge3": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

同じ行なのであくまでも単語単位で一致させたいと思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

除外したい単語

```
"hoge2": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
```

#### 追記

fluentdのfluent-plugin-record-reformerを使ってるのですが、フィールドを正規表現で置換したいので質問させてもらいました。フィールドにはjsonが入っているのですが、特定の項目だけ除外したいのです。

Comment: 正規表現と一口に言っても、どの言語やコマンドで使用するかによって微妙に実装が異なります。可能であれば想定しているプログラミング言語なども書いてもらうと具体的な回答が付きやすいです。

Comment: 質問は見方によっては「除去したい単語」の部分を元の検索文字から削除すれば良さそうですが、これは想定とは違いますか？

Comment: fluentdのfluent-plugin-record-reformerを使ってるのですが、フィールドを正規表現で置換したいので質問させてもらいました。フィールドにはjsonが入っているのですが、特定の項目だけ除外したいのです。

Comment: >質問は見方によっては「除去したい単語」の部分を元の検索文字から削除すれば これは意図通りではありません

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<filter access.nginx.**>
  @type grep
  exclude1 hoge ^hoge
</filter>
```

[fluent-plugin-grep](https://github.com/sonots/fluent-plugin-grep)を使ってhogeに「hoge」が含まれている場合は除外するようにしました。紹介していただいたfluent-plugin-ignore-filterは標準ではないのでちょっと懸念があり今回は断念しました。

Answer (score 0):

`gem install fluent-plugin-ignore-filter`
及び
`sudo td-agent-gem install fluent-plugin-ignore-filter`

として、`ignore-filter`をインストールすることで、例えば

```
<filter access.nginx.**>
  @type ignore
  regexp path 取り除きたいログに対する正規表現
</filter>
```

の様に、regexpで指定した正規表現を含まない行が出力される様になると思います。
`regexp`を`regexp1`, `regexp2`等として複数行書くことで、いずれにもマッチしない行だけが出力されると思います。

`ignore-filter`プラグインの作者の`Qiita`は[こちら](https://qiita.com/bungoume/items/6ec72bd04efa6ccde733)になります

Comment: ありがとうございます！文字列の一部を削除したいと言う意図でしたがfluent-plugin-ignore-filterでも十分でした！こちらは解決したので一旦closeします。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 最終的に標準のgrepで対応しました。ご教授ありがとうございました。https://github.com/sonots/fluent-plugin-grep